# Scrolling Image View with time Duration in Android

Tags: android, animation, uiimageview

I am building an application in which the front page of the app should have a animated imageview. There are about 5-6 images and it should be scrolling either from left to right, the direction doesnt matters but it should scroll anyway.

I tried searching from the net but i found only bring the pic set relevant to time and they seems they dont scroll through the layouts. So if u come to know scrolling the images with time duration let me come to know. I have been moving with this a long time so any suggestions on this is greatly appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

Use android animations :) translation animation to be precise:

```
<set 
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
    <translate 
    android:fromXDelta="0%p" 
    android:toXDelta="-100%" 
    android:duration="5000"
    /> </set>
```

Interpolator is used as the rate the image should scroll with

I hope this helps.